# how to find out if output stream chain is ended?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, stream

**What I am trying to achieve?**

How can I find if a stream chain is ended? Look at the function below (all these functions are inside a LogRouter class in this question):

```
template<typename First, typename... Rest>
void log(const LogLevel &level_, First first_, Rest... rest_) {
    sstream << first_ << " ";
    log(level_, rest_...);
}

void log(const LogLevel &level_) {
    for(auto &route : routes)
        route->stream() << sstream.str() << std::endl;

    sstream.clear();
    sstream.str("");
}
```

I want to achieve the exact same functionality in the above but using streams. So, when I reach an end of a stream it needs to send the final data to the routes and instead of using

```
router.log(LogLevel::Alert, "test stream", 15);
```

I want to be able to use

```
router.log(LogLevel::Alert) << "test stream " << 15;
```

**What I have tried:**

- `std::ostream` operator overloading does not accept packed variables.
- going through every single passed value one by one. Like below:

  ```
   struct LogEnd {};

   static LogEnd end() { return LogEnd; }

   template<typename T> LogRouter &operator<<(const T &value) {
       sstream << value;
       return *this;
   }

   LogRouter &log(const LogLevel &level_) {
       currentLogLevel = level_; //had to add another variable
       return *this;
   }

   void operator<<(const LogEnd &end) {
      for(auto &route : routes)
          route.stream() << sstream.str() << std::endl;
      currentLogLevel = LogLevel::None;
  }
  ```

  This gives me what I want syntax wise but I need to call the additional `LogRouter::end()` at the end of every:

  ```
   router.log(LogLevel::Alert) << "test stream " << 15 << LogRouter::end();
  ```

  I have a syntax for `std::endl` also but it would be best if I can call it without anything in the end.

**Question**

Is there a way to know an end of a stream chain. Something similar to what you can do when using recursive variadic template function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could put the interesting logic into the stream's destructor. Obviously, I would also properly deal with stream rather than cooking up something which somewhat looks like a stream but isn't really a stream:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

class logstream
    : private virtual std::stringbuf
    , public std::ostream {
    std::string level;
public:
    logstream(std::string l)
        : std::ostream(this)
        , level(l) {
    }
    logstream(logstream&& other)
    : std::stringbuf(std::move(other))
    , std::ostream(std::move(other))
    , level(std::move(other.level)) {
        this->rdbuf(0);
    }
    ~logstream() {
        std::cout << "do something interesting here("
                  << this->level<< ", " << this->str() << ")\n";
    }
};

logstream trace() {
    return logstream("trace");
}

int main()
{
    trace() << "hello, world";
}
```

The stream buffer used (`std::stringbuf` in this case but it could also be a custom stream buffer) is made a base class to have it constructed before the `std::ostream`. In principle it is meant to be a data member but data members are constructed after the base classes. Thus, it is made a `private` base class instead.

It turns out that `std::ostream` has a `virtual` base class (`std::ios`) which would cause the `std::ostream` to still be constructed before the `std::stringbuf` if normal inheritance where used for `std::stringbuf`. Using `virtual` inheritance and making the `std::stringbuf` the first base class makes sure it really is constructed first.

Comment: Can you please clarify on why you are deriving a private virtual `std::stringbuf`

Comment: This is  a lovely, compact solution, but how do you compile it?   I'm trying with g++ 4.8 and I'm getting a ton of errors.

Comment: @Bogatyr: first off, you'll need to compile with C++11 enabled (`-std=c++11`) to get rvalue references supported. You'll also need to have a standard library which properly supports move construction for streams. With these, the code compiles as is. I don't know if `libstdc++` shipping with `g++` 4.8 has that properly implemented. If move construction of streams isn't properly supported, you may need to stick the `std::stringbuf` into a `std::unique_ptr<std::streambuf>` and move the pointer instead of the `std::stringbuf`.

Comment: @DietmarKühl What compiler are you using?  I did compile with -std=c++11.    I copied your code onto https://www.codechef.com/ide and selected C++14 (g++ 4.9.2) and got the same errors I got from my g++ 4.8 with -std=c++11, they begin with: logstream.cpp:17:35: error: use of deleted function ‘std::basic_stringbuf<char>::basic_stringbuf(std::basic_stringbuf<char>&&)’
     , level(std::move(other.level))

Comment: @Bogatyr: I got multiple versions of gcc. I can see the problem with gcc-4.9.2 but it doesn't happen with gcc-5.1.0: the standard library shipping with gcc-4.9.2 apparently didn't implement move constructors for streams. However, `std::basic_stringbuf` is clearly specified to have an accessible move constructor in C++11.