# Design a C++ Logger with operator '<<'

Tags: c++, logging, asynchronous, mfc

I am designing a C++ asynchronous lightweight logger. A rough implementation would look like below,

```
ILogger log(fileName, LoggingLevel::WARN)
log << "Hello" << "This is sample warn logging";
```

I am using concurrent queue, so I will upload all the logging messages to concurrent queue and another thread will take messages out of it and write it to a file.

I have a problem though,

My overloaded operator is as follows,

```
ILogger& operator<< (string s)
{
    logStr += s;
    return *this;
    // There should be a point where instead of just returning, I
    // should call queue.add(logStr);
}
```

The problem is I don't know when to stop appending to logStr and flush the string into the concurrent queue.

I donot want a delimiter like endLog to say the log ended. Are there any way to determine the end of "<<" without having a special delimiter

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to find out if output stream chain is ended?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21246317/how-to-find-out-if-output-stream-chain-is-ended)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a helper friend class

```
class LogStream {
    ILogger&            log_;
    std::ostringstream  logS_;
public:
    LogStream(ILogger& log) : log_(log) {
    }
    ~LogStream() {
        log_.queue.add(logS_.str());
    }
    template<typename T>
    LogStream& operator<<(const T& val) {
        logS_ << val;
        return *this;
    }
};
```

and use a `LogStream` object instead of `operator <<`

```
LogStream ILogger::getStream() {
    return LogStream(*this);
}
```

So the logging statement

```
log.getStream() << "Hello" << "This is sample warn logging";
```

will create a temporary `LogStream` object that will accept two strings and then will be deleted (and will append a result string to the logger queue in the destructor) just before the next statement.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having only a single logger object instance, you can create one instance for each logging operation. Then in its destructor you "flush" the queued output.

The file stream(s) (or queues, or whatever you want) where the flushed output should be written can be a static member that is initialized once, and used by each instance.

Comment: Can you be more elaborate. I understand but to have this as acceptable answer, need little more clarity

Answer (score 1):

Why not have your logger accept `std::endl` as a marker to indicate that the log line should be written:

```
log << "Hello" << "This is sample warn logging" << std::endl;
```

This fits in with the whole stream based approach to output in C++ and is a paradigm that most developers are familiar and confortable with.

Comment: Thanks. But I don't want to do this. What if the user accidentally miss out the endl ? He thinks the message is being logged whereas the messages won't

Comment: @MohanKumar That problem, with users forgetting to end their lines or flush the streams, still exists with normal `std::cout`. And yes some of those cases end up here on SO with someone wondering why they don't get output.