# Cant express myself in c++ other than with a macro

Tags: c++, macros, operator-keyword

I have a macro that does exactly what I want it to do:

```
    #define LOG(x)\
    do {  if (!cpp::app::g_app) {\
        ASSERT("CANNOT LOG IF THERE IS NO CPP APP OBJECT" == 0);\
        }\
        else \
        { \
            std::stringstream s; s << cpp::timing::currentDateTime(); s << '\t'; s << x << std::endl; \
            *cpp::app::g_app << s.str(); \
            cpp::app::g_app->flush(true);\
        } \
    } while(0)

#endif
```

Its really nice, because I can:

```
LOG("On first log line " << 0 << "Still on first log line")
```

..and a newline is inserted once the LOG macro is done.

Output looks like:

```
<date / time> On First log line 0 Still on first log line
... subsequent lines here
```

My question is how to overload `<<` operator on my logging class to do the same?

If I simply overload `<<` operator and return *this (where my logging case can be converted to ostream) then if I do:

```
mylogger << "First line " << "Still on first line";
```

then the output is something like:

```
<date and time> First line
<date and time> Still on first line.
```

So, I want to emulate the macro behaviour with the `<<` operator. I want a newline automatically when the whole chain of `<<` operations is complete, just like in the macro. But, since macros are evil, I'd rather convert it to a proper function.

Is this achievable?

Edit: Matt's idea about  a helper class is quite nice. Based on his suggestion, I made the following disposable helper class:

```
    class log
{
public:
    log() :
    m_stream(cpp::app::g_app->stream()){

    }

    template <typename T>
    log& operator << (const T& t)
    {
        m_ss << t;
        return *this;
    }

    virtual ~log(){
        m_stream << cpp::timing::currentDateTime() << "\t" << m_ss.str() << "\r\n";
        m_stream.flush();
    }

private:
    std::ostream& m_stream;
    std::stringstream m_ss;
};
```

Use it like:

```
log() << "All this text" << " will be on one line in the logfile, with date and time prepended ";
log() << "And this lot falls on line 2, with date and time prepended";
```

I hope that helps Galik and others who may be wanting the same thing.

Comment: The way I do it is to have the syntax `log() << "foo" << "bar";` , where `log()` returns a temporary object that does the final output in its destructor

Comment: You may consider a `Logger` class that provides a `std::ostream` to write to, e.g. `std::ostream& Logger::debug()` and use like `logger.debug() << "Blah!" << std::endl;` instead of providing such macro (though it's a safely written one).

Comment: Thanks matt, but I want to type less for the function than I do currently for the macro. Multiplied by the number of times I need to log stuff, its a lot of extra typing when I can just currently say:   LOG("Hello World" << " and " << "Hello Moon"); For a start, I never have to type 'endl' (or in headers std::endl) when I use my macro.

Comment: @rwebby _"its a lot of extra typing"_ Huh what?!?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: What I think he said: "Typing `<< std::endl` once is a little extra typing.  Typing it many times is a lot of extra typing."

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ well, it is. Given the choice between typing endl thousands of times in  a large program, and using a macro that not only automates it,but lets you chain multiple << operations on to one line, which would _you_ choose? Thanks, Ben. You know what I'm on about ;)

Comment: See this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/21246556/701092

Comment: @BenVoigt You may accuse me for using the copy/paste anti-pattern, but I tend to do such for logging statements, and change everything  between `logger.debug() <<` and  `<< std::endl;` as needed (though this could be a bit error prone), I won't start to change my behavior writing this from scratch every time needed. The _extra typing_ argument just looks like a red herring for me here (especially taking intellisense equipped IDE editors into account).

Comment: Post your answer as an answer, not an update to the question :)

Comment: I've wondered how to achieve this for the longest time; not sure why I never thought of @MattMcNabb's solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A small improvement to the solution offered in the question, that creates fewer temporary objects:

```
class log
{
public:
    log() :
    m_stream(cpp::app::g_app->stream()){
    }

    template <typename T>
    std::ostream& operator<< (const T& t)
    {
        return m_stream << cpp::timing::currentDateTime() << "\t" << t;
    }

    virtual ~log(){
        m_stream << "\r\n";
        m_stream.flush();
    }

private:
    std::ostream& m_stream;
};
```

The temporary instance of `log()` will be destroyed at the end of the full-expression even if it isn't returned from `operator<<`.  Might as well get rid of the middle-man and the extra stringstream buffer (which btw, doesn't respect the existing formatting options on the main stream -- this could be good or bad)

Comment: Thanks, I accepted as the answer. Its slightly neater and more efficient than what I came up with as a result of the kind help and comments from others.

Answer (score 1):

I have some code that you may find useful.

Its not heavily tested. I am hoping to expand on this to supply a producer/consumer queue which is why I am not using it at the moment. I am still using a macro like you :)

```
#include <sstream>
#include <memory>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

namespace log {

typedef std::stringstream sss; // <3 brevity

class writer
{
private:
    std::ostream& sink;
    std::string endl = "\n";

    std::string get_stamp()
    {
        time_t rawtime = std::time(0);
        tm* timeinfo = std::localtime(&rawtime);
        char buffer[32];
        std::strftime(buffer, 32, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", timeinfo);

        return std::string(buffer);
    }

public:

    writer(std::ostream& sink): sink(sink) {}

    void add_line(sss* ss)
    {
        sink << get_stamp() << " " << ss->rdbuf() << endl;
    }
};

// this is used to build the log string in an sts::ostringstream
// which gets std::moved to each new temporary buffer when <<
// is invoked
struct buffer
{
    writer& lw;
    sss* ss;

    buffer(writer& lw): lw(lw), ss(new sss) {}
    buffer(const buffer& buf) = delete;
    buffer(buffer&& buf): lw(buf.lw), ss(buf.ss) { buf.ss = nullptr; }
    ~buffer() { if(ss) lw.add_line(ss); delete ss; }
};

// each << creates a new temporary buffer that std::moves
// the std::ostringstream on to the next
template<typename Type>
buffer operator<<(buffer&& buf, const Type& t)
{
    (*buf.ss) << t;
    return std::move(buf);
}

// A write to a writer creates a temporary buffer and passes
// the << on to that
template<typename Type>
buffer operator<<(writer& lw, const Type& t)
{
    return std::move(buffer(lw) << t);
}

} // log

int main()
{
    std::ofstream ofs("output.log");

    log::writer fout(ofs); // write to file

    log::writer lout(std::cout); // write to std output

    lout << "A " << 0.7 << " B";

    fout << "wibble: " << 2;
}
```

The way this works is that writing to a `log::writer` via `<<` causes a temporary `log::buffer` to be created. Subsequent writes `<<` to the `log::buffer` create new temporary `log::buffer` objects which `std::move` an internal `std::ostringstream` between them. Because only the final `log::buffer` object has a non-null `std::ostringstream*` (because it was `std::moved` down when it collapsed) it writes the entire line to the `log::writer`.

Comment: thanks. If it helps, I quickly came up with a temporary log object, as suggested above, which seems to work with the minimum of fuss. If I can work out where to post code in the comments, I will do so. Its only a little class

Comment: @ Galik: See the question. Since I didnt know where else to post it, Ive appended the code that works to the end of the question.

Answer (score 1):

My rather simple take on the situation:

```
class logger{
private:
    unsigned int support_count;
    std::ostream& output_stream;
public:

    logger(std::ostream& str)
        :support_count(0),
          output_stream(str)
    {}

    class support_buffer{
    private:
        logger& l;
        support_buffer(logger& l)
            :l(l)
        {
            l.support_count++;
        }
    public:
        support_buffer(const support_buffer& buf)
            :l(buf.l)
        {
            l.support_count++;
        }

        ~support_buffer(){
            l.support_count--;
            if (l.support_count==0){
                l.output_stream << std::endl;
            }
        }

        template <typename T>
        support_buffer& operator<<(const T& t){
            l.output_stream << t;
            return *this;
        }

        friend class logger;
    };

    template <typename T>
    support_buffer operator<<(const T& t){
        output_stream << "<date/time> " << t;
        return support_buffer(*this);
    }

    friend class support_buffer;
};


int main()
{
    logger l(std::cout);

    l << "Line 1: " << 0 << "Still on line 1";
    l << "Line 2";

    return 0;
}
```

Just create a wrapper class that passes all printed elements to our logger and on destruction of the last one send a new line. If you are sure that your output buffer is only being used by your logger class you could even resign of counting support objects. Just print new line character before a line instead of after it.